# How Datatable holds my edited values

Tags: java, jsf

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{studentBean2.studentList}" var="student">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="STUDENT-ID" />
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputText value="#{student.studentId}" />     
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="STUDENT-NAME" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{student.studentName}" /> 
    </h:column>
    .........
    .........
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{studentBean2.action}" value="ENTER" />
```

As from the above code, datatable values can be edited in `<h:inputText>` field and submitted. Those edited values are seen in `action()` method of bean `StudentBean2`.

As I followed the log, it showed that when I submit the page in the phase "Apply Request Values" the `getStudentList()` method is called. In this method I do the JDBC call to fetch students from the Database and set the newly fetched `studentlist`.

But in the "Invoke Application" phase, in method `action()` I get the edited data in the list which I have submitted. How exactly does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF has set them for you during the update model values phase. During this phase, the `processUpdates()` method of every component will be invoked. In case of the `<h:dataTable>` it's the [`UIData#processUpdates()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#processUpdates%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29). For every row it will then invoke the same method of the input component, which is in your case [`UIInput#processUpdates()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#processUpdates%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29).

Basically:

```
get data model of UIData; // studentList = studentBean2.getStudentList()
for (every row of data model) {
    get the current row item by index; // student = studentList.get(index)
    for (every child UIInput component of UIData) {
        set its value; // student.setStudentName(value)
    }
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, doing the JDBC call inside the getter method is a bad idea. The getter method will be called more than once during bean's life, so the JDBC call will be unnecessarily made too many times. You should make the JDBC call in bean's (post)constructor instead. See also [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times).